# Oracle parsing data between tags from a clob

Tags: oracle, parsing, clob

I have a situation where an application is storing chunks of text in a CLOB.

Each chunk of text is surrounded by a tag
[SYSDATE] (see below for test CASE).

I'm looking for a query that can extract the data between the matching tags. For example, how can I get the text between [11-22-2021 14:16:19]
tags for all matches. In this case 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'

Secondly, is there a better way to handle this situation? Perhaps maybe using XML? All input, ideas and working examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE table t(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
c CLOB DEFAULT ' ',
create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
/


insert into t (c) values (' ')
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lob_append(
  p_clob IN OUT CLOB,
  p_text IN     VARCHAR2
)
AS
  l_text varchar2(32760);
  l_date_string VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

select '[' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ']'
    into l_date_string  from dual;

 
-- newline each time code is appended for clarity.
  l_text :=chr(10) || l_date_string || chr(10)
            || p_text || chr(10)
            || l_date_string||chr(10);

  dbms_lob.writeappend(p_clob, length(l_text), l_text );
END;
/
 

DECLARE
  l_clob CLOB := empty_clob();
lTime date;

BEGIN
lTime := sysdate;

  SELECT c INTO l_clob FROM t WHERE seq_num = 1 FOR UPDATE;

 lob_append(l_clob, rpad('Z',20,'Z'));

loop
        exit when sysdate = lTime + interval '5' second;
     end loop;

l_clob  := empty_clob();
SELECT c INTO l_clob FROM t WHERE seq_num = 1 FOR UPDATE;


lob_append(l_clob, rpad('Y',10,'Y'));


END;
/




SEQ_NUM    C    CREATE_DATE
1     
[11-22-2021 14:16:19]
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
[11-22-2021 14:16:19]

[11-22-2021 14:16:24]
YYYYYYYYYY
[11-22-2021 14:16:24]
11222021 14:15:54
```

Comment: The code to generate test data is a good idea, but did you test it first? That is an absolute must. (I hope you didn't test it - you wouldn't knowingly post wrong code, would you?) I won't say more - let you test it and fix it. Note - after I fixed it, the resulting data in the table looks nothing like what you are showing, either. Test and fix that too.

Comment: @mathguy apologies cut and paste error on my part. I fixed original post. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample CLOB contains newlines; I assumed that is correct, and handled the newlines explicitly. (The solution below assumes each "token" does not contain newlines itself - if it does, then you can modify the `regexp_substr` call slightly, using the option to allow the dot metacharacter to match newlines.)

```
select t.seq_num, l.ord, l.token
from   t cross join lateral
       (
         select level as ord,
                regexp_substr(c, '(\[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])'
                                  || chr(10) || '(.*?)' || chr(10) || '\1'
                             , 1, level, null, 2) 
                as token
         from   dual
         connect by level <= 
                 regexp_count(c, '(\[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])'
                                  || chr(10) || '(.*?)' || chr(10) || '\1')
       ) l
order  by seq_num, ord   --  if needed
;


   SEQ_NUM        ORD TOKEN                    
---------- ---------- -------------------------
         1          1 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ     
         1          2 YYYYYYYYYY
```

Comment: thanks for your help and expertise. Is there a way to display date string which encapsulates the data. This way the user will know when it was added to the clob

Comment: @Pugzly - yes, of course there is. How to do it depends on how, exactly, you want it shown. In my query, if you look at the `regexp_substr` function, it has six arguments. The last one is a hard-coded 2; this means the function will return the second "capture group" (fragment enclosed in parentheses). If you replace that with 1, you will get the date (enclosed in brackets). From there it's easy to just get the date.  Note though that it will be a **string**; whether it will make sense as a **date**, without an explicit `to_date()`, depends on NLS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Added create_date to output

```
SELECT  T.SEQ_NUM,
        L.ORD,
        L.CREATE_DATE,
        L.TOKEN
FROM  T,
        LATERAL(
                SELECT  LEVEL ORD,
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                                      C,
                                      '\[(.{19})\]',
                                      1,
                                      LEVEL * 2 - 1,
                                      null,
                                      1
                                     ) CREATE_DATE,
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                                      C,
                                      '(\[.{19}\])(' ||
                                      CHR(10) || '|' || CHR(13) || ')*(.*)(' ||
                                      CHR(10) || '|' || CHR(13) || ')\1',
                                      1,
                                      LEVEL,
                                      'n',
                                      3
                                     ) TOKEN
                  FROM  DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(
                                                   C,
                                                   '(\[.{19}\])(' ||
                                                   CHR(10) || '|' || CHR(13) || ')*(.*)(' ||
                                                   CHR(10) || '|' || CHR(13) || ')\1'
                                                  )
               ) L
order  by seq_num, ord;

SEQ_NUM ORD CREATE_DATE TOKEN
1   1   12-01-2021 05:53:22 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
1   2   12-01-2021 05:53:24 YYYYYYYYYY
```